# Adding a string/digit with the map-get output sass

Tags: css, sass

I am trying to add a value let say `90` with the map-get output.

I tried simply adding `90` as a string, let say the map-get output is white color,`#ffffff`.

```
color: map-get(map-get($valuemap, $key), color)+"90";
```

Dart sass compiles it as invalid property, `"#ffffff90"`

How can I get from `"#fff90"` to `#fff90`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out you can simply get the value inside quotes `""` with #{} in sass.

Changed this

```
color: map-get(map-get($valuemap, $key), color)+"90";
```

To

```
color: map-get(map-get($valuemap, $key), color)+#{"90"};
```

Dart sass will compile `#ffffff + #{"90"}` into a valid output, `#ffffff90`